# fmdb locks application when running UPDATE-query

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, mobile, fmdb

I'm having trouble executing an UPDATE-query with fmdb. It locks the application without any errors.

It stops at this line:

```
[db executeUpdate:@"UPDATE categories SET number_places = 21 WHERE id = 44"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are your other threads doing?  If you're using fmdb across multiple threads, you should check out FMDatabaseQueue, and use that in place of using FMDatabase directly.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation and couldn't figure out why my application locked up.

Further investigation lead to the conclusion that I had left the FMDatabase connection open in a previous method call.

As soon as I closed the connection and executed a new query with a new connection everything worked fine.